# Is the hunting rifle the possibly strongest ballistic weapon?

Tags: fallout-4

As a Sniper, I wonder which base-weapon is the best. I wanna shoot normal projectiles and get the most out of it using modifications.

[I found this page on the wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_weapons#Rifles), which tells me that the Hunting Rifle is the way to go. Is this even true after applying all mods to a weapon?

PS: My main interests are:

- Damage
- Availability of munition (a sniper which I can always use)

Comment: It depends on what you want from the gun.  You could just use the railway rifle if you just want the most damage per shot. http://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496881136901235755/ the third comment here will be helpful.

Comment: @Aequitas: I edited the post. But is this still true after applying all the mods? Or does (for instance) the Hunting Rifle have stronger modifications in the end?

Comment: Every weapon in F4 that isn't a melee weapon is a projectile weapon. Did you perhaps mean ballistic weapon (ie a weapon that propels mass)?

Comment: @Dallium: Yeah, that sounds better.

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for the highest damage per shot or highest damage in a time frame? The time allowed to weapon will change a lot their damage as the more shots there is, the more damage there can be.

Comment: Dmg per shot. I want as much one shot kills as possible. :) But the answer seems to be the hunting rifle or the nail gun. I think I stick to a hunting rifle.

Comment: [Gauss Rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gauss_rifle_%28Fallout_4%29) seems the best option for damage for 1 shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're aiming for the highest damage per bullet, you should have a look at the Railway Rifle. It starts out with considerably higher damage unmodded in comparison to the Hunting Rifle.

However, you might feel it has a very "un-snipery" feel to it because it does not look in the slightest like a weapon made for sniping in the usual sense. In that case, yes, the Hunting Rifle is your best bet. I had no raw one at hand, so here are the fully modded stats of a Lucky Hunting Rifle with all damage and sniping components:

[image: Gun Stats]

I would look thoroughly for a rifle with a good legendary mod though, seeing as 139 damage is pretty meagre in higher difficulties. Aim for one of these: (somewhat in order of expected payoff)

- Instigating: Does double damage if the target is at full health.
- Two shot: Fires an additional projectile. Decrease in accuracy.
- Junkie's: Does increased amounts of damage the more withdrawal effects you are suffering. (if you're into chems. I read the damage goes up pretty high)
- Mighty/Powerful: Deals an additional 25% damage.
- Lucky Weapon:    Critical shots do double damage and the critical meter fills 15% faster. (If you're into using V.A.T.S.)
- Penetrating: Ignores 30% of the target's damage and energy resistance.

EDIT:

Ammunition did not pose a problem for me. As you can see on the screencap, I have ~1200 shots. Another 1500 are on Nick because I gave him a similar weapon. A clip for the best magazine mod holds 10 bullets if I'm not mistaken, with which, when looking at the Fire Rate, it generally takes FOREVER to deplete 1000+ rounds.

Also, if you pick up the Scrounger perk (additional ammo found throughout the world), you will find boat loads of .50 ammo. This stuff is everywhere and I have absolutely no use for it. Maybe it's just a troll and you'll find plasma cells when you're using that Hunting Rifle, who knows...

Comment: Nice! Yeah, I'm currently looking for an "Instigating" one (I don't play with followers), but I figured that this is probably going to be a long road. :)

Comment: How does a fully modded laser musket compare to this? (fully cranked)

Answer (score 11):

[The Gauss Rifle](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Gauss_rifle_(Fallout_4)) not only has the highest damage of any weapon save the Fat Man and variants, but can be mounted with a silencer and every scope in the game. It's a little heavy at 15 FWU, and the ammo is relatively rare, but nothing beats it for long distance, precision damage. The biggest wrinkle is getting used to the charge time.

Comment: Gauss rifle is definitely the highest single shot rifle.

Comment: That's not what this question is about, but thanks.

Comment: @TrudleR how so?

Comment: I asked for projectile weapons, not plasma or electric (or whatever) :-)

Comment: @TrudleR and? The gauss rifle fires a 2mm chunk of ferromagnetic metal

Comment: Ok then. :c I thought is was from another section.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau the gauss rifle's listed damage is per click. Charging doubles that. Gauss Rifle has a higher ROF than Railway Rifle.

Comment: Also, according to [this wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gauss_rifle_%28Fallout_4%29), `Its raw damage output per shot is outclassed only by the 6-crank Laser musket and the Fat Man and its variants. `

Answer (score 1):

The Railway Rifle does considerably more damage than any of the other rifles.

However it can't be silenced and it weighs quite a lot.

The ammo can be quite scarce, however they are cheap to buy and can be recovered from enemies killed using this weapon.